# How to sort object according to nested array elements

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need to sort the main data by the oldest created account.
In the example below, the first element in the list would be id = 2. That's because the id = 2 contains the oldest created account (named account3, which was created at 2020-10-05, while the other accounts have been created after that date).
I'm using nodejs. Is there an es-function that can solve this problem in an easy way?

The object data looks like this:

```js
{
  "data": [{
    "id": 1,
    "accounts": [{
      "id": 333,
      "data": {
        "name": "account1",
        "createdAt": "2020-10-07T09:27:28.032Z"
      }
    }]
  }, {
    "id": 2,
    "accounts": [{
      "id": 334,
      "data": {
        "name": "account2",
        "createdAt": "2020-10-06T09:27:28.032Z"
      }
    }, {
      "id": 335,
      "data": {
        "name": "account3",
        "createdAt": "2020-10-05T09:27:28.032Z"
      }
    }]
  }]
}
```

Comment: Please take a look at [ask] and produce a [mcve] of your effort with expected output

Comment: it would be better if you fetch this data sorted from your database it would be more efficient

Comment: Data is in elasticsearch. I wanted to avoid to sort it there because Im afraid I would need to use painless-script to achieve that, which is also quite difficult.

Comment: Also you have a data element and two other array elements

Comment: Yes but it is the way it looks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can often solve this problem with `map` --> `sort` --> `map`.
It does 3 passes on the input but remains `O(n log n)`. You could further optimize, but I doubt this becomes a bottleneck.

1. Map to `[record, oldestAccountDate]` tuples.
2. Sort the tuples by `oldestAccountDate`.
3. Map again to unwrap the record.

```js
const wrapper = {
  "data": [{
    "id": 1,
    "accounts": [{
      "id": 333,
      "data": {
        "name": "account1",
        "createdAt": "2020-10-07T09:27:28.032Z"
      }
    }]
  }, {
    "id": 2,
    "accounts": [{
      "id": 334,
      "data": {
        "name": "account2",
        "createdAt": "2020-10-06T09:27:28.032Z"
      }
    }, {
      "id": 335,
      "data": {
        "name": "account3",
        "createdAt": "2020-10-05T09:27:28.032Z"
      }
    }]
  }]
};

wrapper.data = wrapper.data
  .map(rec => [rec, Math.min(...rec.accounts.map(acc => new Date(acc.data.createdAt)))])
  .sort((a, b) => a[1] - b[1])
  .map(tuple => tuple[0]);
  
  
 console.log(wrapper);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const data = [{
  "id": 1,
  "accounts": [{
    "id": 333,
    "data": {
      "name": "account1",
      "createdAt": "2020-10-07T09:27:28.032Z"
    }
  }]
}, {
  "id": 2,
  "accounts": [{
    "id": 334,
    "data": {
      "name": "account2",
      "createdAt": "2020-10-06T09:27:28.032Z"
    }
  }, {
    "id": 335,
    "data": {
      "name": "account3",
      "createdAt": "2020-10-05T09:27:28.032Z"
    }
  }]
}]

const sorted = data.sort((a, b) => {
  const aOldestDate = a.accounts.reduce((acc, item) => {
    const itemDate = new Date(item.data.createdAt);
    return itemDate < acc && itemDate || acc;
  }, new Date());
  
  const bOldestDate = b.accounts.reduce((acc, item) => {
    const itemDate = new Date(item.data.createdAt);
    return itemDate < acc && itemDate || acc;
  }, new Date());
  
  return aOldestDate - bOldestDate;
});

console.log(sorted);
```

Comment: You can do that but it becomes `O(n * n log n)` complexity because you re-resolve the oldest account for every compare.

Comment: @plalx, thank you very much for your comment. I am a self-thought developer with no formal education in CS; many "theoretical" arguments like algorithms complexity are not (yet) something I am familiar with. That is a topic I'll have to learn sooner rather than later. :)